# Apply a CSS class to selected text in Content Editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I'm trying to add a class to selected text when a button is pressed. Right now, for some reason my code applies the class to the button when it is pressed but I want it to apply to the selected text itself.

This is what I have:

I need the button to be a `div`, and that could possibly be the problem, but I just want the highlighted text to get the class, not the button.

Thanks...

```js
function addAnimation() {
  document.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'span');
  selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
  selectedElement.className += "grad";
}
```

```css
.textField {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.grad {
     -webkit-animation: changeColor 8s ease-in infinite;
   animation: changeColor 8s ease-in infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
  0% {color: #ff7473;}
  25% {color: #ffc952;}
  50% {color: #fc913a}
  75% {color: #75D701;}
  100% {color: #ff7473}
}
```

```html
<div class="textField" contenteditable="true">Hello world. Select this text and press the button</div>

<div onclick="addAnimation()">Animate
            </div>
```

Comment: When you click the button, than it is the selected element, think wider to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the virtual button, then the selection is gone. You need to bind to `mousedown` event this way:

```js
function addAnimation() {
    selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
    $(selectedElement).addClass('grad');
}
$('.animate-selected').on('mousedown', addAnimation);
```

```css
.text-field {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

.grad {
    -webkit-animation: changeColor 8s ease-in infinite;
    animation: changeColor 8s ease-in infinite;
}

.animate-selected{
    margin: 2px 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
    0% {
        color: #ff7473;
    }
    25% {
        color: #ffc952;
    }
    50% {
        color: #fc913a
    }
    75% {
        color: #75D701;
    }
    100% {
        color: #ff7473
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-field" contenteditable="true">
    Hello world. Select this text and press the button
</div>
<div class="animate-selected">
    Animate
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va5jak95/).

In case you want to animate only the selected text, than you do it this way:

```js
function addAnimation() {
    $('.grad').contents().unwrap(); /* this removes previous animation */
    var selectedText = window.getSelection();
    var container = $(selectedText.anchorNode.parentNode);
    var wrappedText = '<span class="grad">' + selectedText + '</span>'
    container.html(container.html().replace(selectedText, wrappedText));
}
$('.animate-selected').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    addAnimation();
});
```

```css
.text-field {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

.grad {
    -webkit-animation: changeColor 8s ease-in infinite;
    animation: changeColor 8s ease-in infinite;
}

.animate-selected{
    margin: 2px 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeColor {
    0% {
        color: #ff7473;
    }
    25% {
        color: #ffc952;
    }
    50% {
        color: #fc913a
    }
    75% {
        color: #75D701;
    }
    100% {
        color: #ff7473
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-field" contenteditable="true">
    Hello world. Select this text and press the button
</div>
<div class="animate-selected">
    Animate
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va5jak95/1/).

Comment: that sort of worked, but it doesn't add the class to the selected text.. it adds it to _all_ the text... any ideas?

Comment: You would have to wrap the selected text only inside some `span` to make it work.

Comment: I've added you an example of how to do it.